# refresh another url by clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, html

hi can anyone help me with this prob,

suppose m working with employee/refresh1.php in which i have a button as follows

when i click on this submit button employee/refresh2.php has to refresh

in refresh2.php i have followinf func

```
echo(rand(10,100));
```

so onclick of submit button new random numbers has to be generated. i have seen several functions but it helps in refreshing same page but my problem is i have refresh another page onclick of submit button which is in different page.

Comment: Your code will just display a random number on the screen. What does it have to do with page refreshing?

Comment: you are working with parent window?

Comment: it has to generate new random number every time

Comment: You should use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to do an async call to refresh2.php

Comment: better u just refresh that perticular DIV which holds function of random number generator

Comment: i need using javasript

Comment: used this window.parent.location = "http://yourpage.com/";

Answer (score 0):

You have to give name to new window when you open, then call onClick event [name of new window].location.href = href;
href will be url of new page that you want to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This will refresh the div and print the  `output` of `refresh2.php` in `refreshDIV`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#refreshDIV").click(function(){
           $("#refreshDIV").load('refresh2.php');
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="refreshDIV">
    Click here to load
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by **refreshing** the employee/refresh2.php page??? does it mean that every time you click the button, you get **redirected to that page** and it shows the output you want...or instead that the current page  fetches the new random values every time from the employee/refresh2.php page and show it to you on employee/refresh1.php page???

If latter is the case then you need to learn the basics of ajax... 
suppose this is the coding in your employee/refresh.html page

```
     <body>
        <input type="submit" onclick="dothis()"> 
        <script>
    function dothis()
    {
        if(windows.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        elseif(windows.ActiveXObject)
        {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

        }
 $url="employee/refresh2.php?q";
        xmlhttp.open("Get",$url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
        </script>
        <div id="demo"></div>

        </body>

    and then on employee/refresh2.php page do this<br>

        <?php if(isset['q'])
        echo (rand(10,100));
        ?>
```